# Javascript: Combine 2 indices from an array into 1 index. Ex [ '2', '3', '5', '(G1)', '2'] into ['2', '3', '5 (G1)', '2']

Tags: javascript, arrays

first time posting here so thank you in advance for any help. I am working with Javascript.

I have one array: `[ '2', '3', '5', '(G1)', '2']`

that I would like to change into `['2', '3', '5 (G1)', '2']`

Put another way, I would like to combine index 2 & 3 into one index. Anytime a G1/G2/G3 appears in the array I would like to join it with the previous number.

Is this possible?

Edit: I had previously tried searching for joining and merging indices, however I did not think to search for .reduce or .match etc. I did look through other posts here as well to see if a similar question had previously been asked. I will be more careful in the details I provide next time (ie all array items are strings).

Thank you to those that took the time to answer, the solutions provided work.

Comment: what is `(G1)`? is it a string?

Comment: it's a set or a function ? if it's a function and return type is array use spread operation `...` and it will work

Comment: @chazsolo it is a string

Comment: @Azeem Aslam I am new to coding, so I am not familiar with the term set yet. However if Google provided me with the same definition you have (data type storing unique values without any particular order) then that is almost correct, except the (G1) values will always appear after a number 5 or higher.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the G-strings (no pun intended… at first) will always begin with a parenthesis and the other strings won't, then we can match by that parenthesis and reduce the strings. Will you ever have multiple G-strings in a row?

The steps here will be:

1. Check to see if each current value starts with `(G` and ends with `)`.
2. If so, we will add that string to the previous value `a[a.length-1]`, separated by a single space.
3. If not, we will simply push the item to the accumulator array normally.
4. With each iteration, we will return the updated accumulator `a`.

This should work for your provided example:

```js
let before = ['2', '3', '5', '(G1)', '2'];
let after = before.reduce((a,c,i) => ((i && c.slice(0,2) === "(G" && c.slice(-1) === ")" ? (a[a.length-1] = `${a[a.length-1]} ${c}`) : a.push(c)), a), []);

console.log(after);
```

**Output:**

```js
['2', '3', '5 (G1)', '2']
```

This will also work for more complex examples, where a G-string might be the first item, so we will push it normally to the array, and where there may be multiple G-strings in a row:

```js
let before = ['(G1)', '2', '3', '5', '(G2)', '(G3)', '2', '(G4)', '6'];
let after = before.reduce((a,c,i) => ((i && c.slice(0,2) === "(G" && c.slice(-1) === ")" ? (a[a.length-1] = `${a[a.length-1]} ${c}`) : a.push(c)), a), []);

console.log(after);
```

**Output:**

```js
['(G1)', '2', '3', '5 (G2) (G3)', '2 (G4)', '6']
```

Comment: @Sam I added a check as well to ensure that a G-string is not the first item in the array. If it ever is, it will simply push the array item to the array normally.

Comment: Hi @Brandon McConnell, thank you so much for showing me your solution, and for taking the time to write an explanation!

Comment: Sure thing. Thanks, @Sam!

Answer (score 0):

You could check the element and add to the previous item.

```js
const
    data = [2, 3, 5, '(G1)', 2],
    result = data.reduce((r, v) => {
        if (v.toString().match(/\(G\d+\)/)) r[r.length - 1] += ' ' + v;
        else r.push(v);
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: as i understand the question, the pattern occurs only with a number before ... but anyway, it chould be sanitised, if necessary.

Comment: Hi @Nina Scholz, you're absolutely right in your assumption. As expected, your answer works and it is very elegantly written. Thank you so much for taking the time to help me!